# Hadoop error when outputting the grep results to a new file in a different directory

Tags: hadoop, grep, hdfs, ioerror

I'm trying to read the contents of a few files and using grep find the lines with the my search query and then output the results into a folder in another directory.  I get an error "No such file or directory exists".  I have created the folder structure and the text file.

```
hadoop fs -cat /Final_Dataset/c*.txt | grep 2015-01-* > /energydata/2015/01/01.txt
```

ERROR:

-bash: /energydata/2015/01/01.txt: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CLI command worked

```
hadoop fs -cat /FinalDataset/c*.txt | grep 2015-01-* | hadoop fs -put - /energydata/2015/01/output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

`> /energydata/2015/01/01.txt` means that the output is being redirected to a **local** file. `hdfs fs -cat` sends output to your local machine and at that point you're no longer operating within Hadoop. `grep` simply acts on a stream of data, it doesn't care (or know) where it came from.

You need to make sure that `/energydata/2015/01/` exists locally before you run this command. You can create it with `mkdir -p /energydata/2015/01/`.

If you're looking to pull certain records from a file on HDFS and then re-write the new file to HDFS then I'd suggest not `cat`-ing the file and instead keeping the processing entirely on the cluster, by using something like Spark or Hive to transform data efficiently. Or failing that just do a `hadoop dfs -put <local_path> /energydata/2015/01/01.txt`.